# Some applications can't run when run as root on Yosemite

Tags: mac-app-store

I deleted App Store on my Macbook, and reinstalled it using the Combo Updater 10.6.6. Now, when I run it, it starts dancing in the dock briefly and then just disappears, and doesn't run any more. I experienced this with some other applications as well, for example Paint 2. Could someone explain what's going on?

Comment: It appears your only solution is to reinstall Yosemite [support article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13871?locale=en_US) and [similar discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26302887#26302887)

Comment: The solution might be to install a version of App Store made sometime in the last 5 years… not one from when it was first ever released. You could try the combo for 10.10.3 but idk whether it would be on there. Only other solution would be to get it from a full installer & see if Pacifist or similar can install it, or just get it from your backup...

Comment: I instaled the combo update 10.10.3 and App store seems to stick in Dock, but won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.6.6 didn't have the AppStore. It was added at 10.6.8, therefore I assumed you had this.

Okay, that won't work on Yosemite (10.10.x).

Therefore, delete it again via Terminal "sudo rm -rfv /Applications/App\ Store.app/"

Next step, rebooting the computer, holding CMR key and R pressed. You'll end up either in the local recovery or if not present, your computer will download the internet recovery. And now choose 'reinstall OS X' This will give you back any missing system files without deleting anything.

Comment: Command and "r" key?

Comment: My macbook is Macbook7.1 (mid-2010). Do you think it is safe to do the Internet OSX recovery? I will surely try that in this case, because, installing the combo update 10.10.3 didn't work. I am still trying to install AppStore from combo update using Pacifist though. Maybe this will work, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: It's perfectly safe. Mid-2010? Some models do have the internet recovery. Others don't. This year is kind of split. Normally internet recovery will bring you down to the first system, but not with a 2010. On these models, they were upgraded to 10.10, since the do have a cd to downgrade. So of you have one, it's perfectly safe and of not, well than we'll use some trickery. Just check for it. Local recovery is always perfectly safe here.

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem - suficiently. The Appstore is alive again, and working ok.